# Capture error code in PowerShell and skip commands

Tags: powershell

I have a simple PowerShell script utilizing ImageMagick to combine ImageFile and then delete the directory were the files were at.  What I need to do, is when an error is reported [displayed in command window]  If an error is detected, we would want the script to skip the commands where the remove command is.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
$srcfolder = "C:\Work\Test2"
$combine = "C:\Work\Scripts\Tools\ImageMagick\convert.exe "
$arg1 = " -compress zip "
$condition = "false"
#-------------------------------------------------------------------
Write-Host "Start"
foreach ($srcitem in $(Get-ChildItem -Path $srcfolder -Recurse -File -Include ('*.tif','*.g42') | Select -ExpandProperty DirectoryName -Unique))
{

$cmdline= $combine + "'"+$srcitem+"\*'"+$arg1 +"'"+$srcitem+".tif'"
    Write-Host $cmdline
    invoke-expression -command $cmdline
    $msg = command 2>&1
    
    if ($msg)
        {
            $condition = "true"
            Write-Output "The condition is true, skip"
        }

    if ( $condition )
        {
            Write-Output "The Condition was false, remove."
            Remove-Item -path $srcitem -recurse
        }

}
```

Comment: It might be as simple as adding `if ($LASTEXITCODE) { continue }` after your command which will check if your command exited with an error code and if so continue to next item skipping the rest of the code in your foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

I edited the script you posted. I did not test any of this code. You have a couple ways to address error handling but here are 2:

**Option 1: Trap every error** 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_trap

```
trap {
    Write-Warning $error[0]
    continue
}
$srcfolder = "C:\Work\Test2"
$combine = "C:\Work\Scripts\Tools\ImageMagick\convert.exe "
$arg1 = " -compress zip "
$condition = "false"
#-------------------------------------------------------------------
Write-Host "Start"
foreach ($srcitem in $(Get-ChildItem -Path $srcfolder -Recurse -File -Include ('*.tif', '*.g42') | Select -ExpandProperty DirectoryName -Unique)) {

    $cmdline = $combine + "'" + $srcitem + "\*'" + $arg1 + "'" + $srcitem + ".tif'"
    Write-Host $cmdline
    invoke-expression -command $cmdline
    $msg = command 2>&1
    
    if ($msg) {
        $condition = "true"
        Write-Output "The condition is true, skip"
    }

    if ( $condition ) {
        Write-Output "The Condition was false, remove."
        Remove-Item -path $srcitem -recurse
    }

}
```

**Option 2: Try Catch** 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally

```
$srcfolder = "C:\Work\Test2"
$combine = "C:\Work\Scripts\Tools\ImageMagick\convert.exe "
$arg1 = " -compress zip "
$condition = "false"
#-------------------------------------------------------------------
Write-Host "Start"
foreach ($srcitem in $(Get-ChildItem -Path $srcfolder -Recurse -File -Include ('*.tif', '*.g42') | Select -ExpandProperty DirectoryName -Unique)) {
    $cmdline = $combine + "'" + $srcitem + "\*'" + $arg1 + "'" + $srcitem + ".tif'"
    Write-Host $cmdline
    try {
        invoke-expression -command $cmdline -ErrorAction Stop
        $msg = command 2>&1
        if ($msg) {
            $condition = "true"
            Write-Output "The condition is true, skip"
        }

        if ( $condition ) {
            Write-Output "The Condition was false, remove."
            Remove-Item -path $srcitem -recurse
        }
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning $error[0]
        continue
    }
}
```